# htaccess redirect loop issue when using two frameworks

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-2

I am using two separate frameworks for my websites Front End (codeIgniter) and Back End (Rain Framework), but the issue is when I have uploaded the code on server It gives the error "This webpage has a redirect loop" for the backend (while the front end is working fine), the problem must be occurred due to .htaccess, I have tried to find the solution on google but nothing works for me please If someone can help me to resolve this issue, my .htaccess file are

for front end ::

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|adminpanel|web)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and for back end ::

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /adminpanel/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|adminpanel|web)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

my admin folder is adminpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite this line in front end

```
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|web)
```

back end

```
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|adminpanel)
```